# Jenkins build common module before build WAR file

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have a maven project as structure module as below :-

- Parent
- Common
- Report

In common module, once compiled I will get the JAR file as final output
Then I will execute report module using the common JAR inside my WAR file.

I wanted to use Jenkins to compile common to update the JAR file then compile the report module to build the WAR and deploy into Tomcat ( using Jenkins )

Is there can be done using report pom.xml (single pom file ) to build common and report ?

Is there any better approach? Please advise

Answer (score 0):

You can have one job that builds Common module and another for Report. In Report job specify that it should be triggered after Common is successfully  built.

[image]